# Close UIAlertView and Replace with Another

Tags: iphone, service, location, uialertview

I'm running an application that requires LocationServices be enabled.  I'm checking if they are by making a call to the service and catching the error.  In the error case, I want to pop up an alertview notifying the user to activate location services.  I have another AlertView open already when this test happens.  I want to close that one and give the user the dialog box I mentioned previously.

Currently, I have

```
case kCLErrorDenied: // CL access has been denied (eg, user declined location use)

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"NOTICE" 
               message:@"Sorry, this application needs your location.  Please select 'Allow' when asked to use your current location.  You don't need to be on or near the trail."
                 delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:nil 
              otherButtonTitles:@"EXIT"];
   [alert show];
   [alert release];
   //exit(0);
   break;
```

This causes the app to just exit.  I had an NSLog output in there so I know it gets to this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you are specifying delegate:self, then it searches for alert handlers declared at UIAlertViewDelegate and when it doesn't find it crashes.

So you should define

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

in your class.

Also you can implement other methods of UIAlertViewDelegate which will help you in your required task.

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that too.  I put some handling code in there and it works great now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the previous alert with an instance variable, and call the method to dismiss that previous dialog before showing the new one. You also need a delegate handler for the alert.